# Pros and Cons of Cassandra User Defined Functions

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using Apache Cassandra to store mostly time series data. And I am grouping the data and aggregating/counting it based on some conditions. At the moment I am doing this in a Java 8 application, but with the release of Cassandra 3.0 and the User Defined Functions, I have been asking myself if extracting the grouping and aggregation/counting logic to Cassandra is a good idea. To my understanding this functionallity is something like the stored procedures in SQL.

My concern is if this will impact the computation performance and the overall performance of the database. I am also not sure if there are other issues with it and if this new feature is something like the secondary indexes in Cassandra - you can do them, but it is not recommended at all.

Have you used user defined functions in Cassandra? Do you have any observations on the performance? What are the good and bad sides of this new functionality? Is it applicable in my use case?

Answer (score 5):

You can compare it to using `count()` or `avg()` kind of aggregations. They can save you a lot of network traffic and object creation/GC by having the coordinator only send the result, but its easy to get carried away and make the coordinator do a lot of work. This extra work takes away from normal C* duties, and can just as likely increase GCs as reduce them.

If your aggregating 100 rows in a partition its probably fine and if your aggregating 10000 its probably not end of the world if its very rare. If your calling it once a second though its a problem. If your aggregating over 1000 I would be very careful.

If you absolutely need to do it and its a lot of data often, you may want to create dedicated proxy coordinators (-Djoin_ring=false) to bear the brunt of the load without impacting normal C* read/writes. At that point its just as easy to create dedicated workload DC for it or something (with RF=0 for your keyspace, and set application to be part of that DC with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy). This also is the point where using Spark is probably the right thing to do.